# (JAXB) Recuperar arquivo XML nos campos de entrada de um formulário JSwing com Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, swing, jaxb

Sou novato e comecei a aprender esses dias XML por conta de uma implementação que deve ter na minha aplicação, fiz alguns testes com marshall e unmarshall na classe main primeiramente (vide no final) para entender melhor, estou fazendo um formulário que deve ter a seguinte operação: O usuário clica no botão Procurar XML então seleciona um arquivo no formato XML de alguma pasta do sistema para depois importar ele para a aplicação aonde será lido por cada campo de texto, o que estou tentando fazer é quando ele importar ele para o sistema ele possa ser lido e em cada tag de ser respectivo valor ele seja carregado para uma das caixas de input (JTextField, JComboBox)...

Exemplo:

```html
<Pedido>
   <pedidos>
   <pedido id = "1">
      <dataCadastro>3917-04-11T00:00:00-03:00</dataCadastro>  <!-- tfDataCadastro: getText(); -->
      <nomeProduto>Produto C</nomeProduto>     <!-- cbProduto.getSelectedItem(); -->
      <numControle>41666</numControle>    <!-- tfNumControle: getText(); -->
      <quantidade>4</quantidade>    <!-- tfQuantidade: getText(); -->
      <valorUnitario>41.46</valorUnitario>    <!-- tfValorUnitario: getText(); -->
      <codCliente>6</codCliente>     <!-- cbCodCliente.getSelectedItem(); -->
   </pedido>
</Pedido>

<!-- As tags comentadas são os valores a serem recuperados -->
```

Tentei fazer assim:

DAOManager:

```js
public interface DAOManager {
    
    ClienteDAO getClienteDAO();
    
    PedidoDAO getPedidoDAO();
    
    ProdutoDAO getProdutoDAO();
}
```

Pedido:

```js
@XmlRootElement(name = "pedido")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {
    
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @XmlElement(name="dataCadastro")
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataCadastro;

    @XmlElement(name="nomeProduto")
    @Column
    private String nomeProduto;

    @XmlElement(name="numControle")
    @Column
    private int numControle;

    @XmlElement(name="quantidade")
    @Column
    private int quantidade;

    @XmlElement(name="valorUnitario")
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorUnitario;

    @XmlElement(name="codCliente")
    @Column
    private Integer codCliente;

    @XmlElement(name="valorTotal")
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorTotal;

    @XmlElement(name="total")
    @Column(precision=2, scale=2)
    private Double total;

    
    public Pedido() {
    }
    
    
    public Pedido(int numControle, Date dataCadastro, String nomeProduto, float valorUnitario, float valorTotal, int quantidade, int codCliente, Double total){
        this.numControle = numControle;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
        this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.codCliente = codCliente;
        this.total = total;
    }

    /* Getters e setters del la aplicación */
         
    
}
```

MySQLPedidoDAO:

```js
/**
 *
 * @author Vickz
 */
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    //null pointer exception pois esse campo estava inicializado como null antes
    public ConnectionFactory cf;

    
    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void inserir(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //tanto persist quanto merge salvam o objeto no banco de dados 
        //em.persist(cliente);
        cf.createEm().merge(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void alterar(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
        pedido.getId();
        cf.createEm().merge(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        cf.createEm().remove(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisar(Long id) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //erro abaixo
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, id);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Pedido> listar() {
        cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //pedido = *, Pedido = nome da tabela
        Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select pedido from Pedido pedido");
        List<Pedido> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
        return pedidos;
    }

    
}
```

ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private DAOManager manager;
    private PedidoModel model;
    private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
    private MySQLClienteDAO mscdao;
    private MySQLProdutoDAO msprdao;
    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private List<Pedido> pedidos;
    private Pedido ped;
    private Produto pro;
    private FiltroArquivo filter;
    private String xmlFile = "";
    private boolean editavel;
    private JAXBContext context;
 
    /* ....  Getters e Setters .... */

    private void btImportarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {
            habilitarTextFieldEBotoes();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImportarPedidoList.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Pedido pedido = (Pedido) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlFile));
            // Como fazer isso?!
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Não foi possível importar o arquivo.xml", "Falha ao carregar", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                          


    private void btProcurarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {
            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Users\\Vickz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Loja");
            jFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Escolha o arquivo xml");
            jFileChooser.setFileFilter(new FiltroArquivo(".xml", "Arquivo XML"));
            int result = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, jFileChooser.getName());
                xmlFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Não foi possível carregar o arquivo.xml", "Falha ao carregar", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                          

                 
/*
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {

        if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          String value = ie.getItem().toString();
          // faz algo conforme a opção selecionada
          if (value.equals("Produto A")) {

          } else if (value.equals("Produto B")) {
          
          } else if (value.equals("Produto C")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto D")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto E")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto F")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto G")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto H")) {
               
          } else if (value.equals("Produto I")) {
                            
          }
       }
    }*/

}
```

Tentei de várias formas fazer ele no main mas também não está dando certo

```js
public class Main {

    private static JAXBContext context;
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
    MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao = new MySQLPedidoDAO(cf);
    PedidoList pl = new PedidoList();
    

    Main.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pedido.class);
    //Marshaller marshaller = Main.context.createMarshaller();
    //marshaller.marshal(new Pedido(41666, new java.util.Date(2017, 3, 11), "Produto C", 41.46f, 0, 4, 6, 235.54), new File("pedido.xml"));
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Main.context.createUnmarshaller();
    Pedido pedidolist = (Pedido) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\Vickz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Loja\\pedido.xml"));
    
    Marshaller marshaller = Main.context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(pedidolist, System.out);
    
    
    /*for(PedidoList pedidolis: unmarshalledPedido.getPedidos()){
         System.out.println(pedido.getDataCadastro());
         System.out.println(pedido.getNomeProduto());
         System.out.println(pedido.getNumControle());
         System.out.println(pedido.getQuantidade());
         System.out.println(pedido.getValorUnitario());
         System.out.println(pedido.getCodCliente());
         System.out.println(pedido.getValorTotal());
         System.out.println(pedido.getTotal());
    }*/
}
```

Tem alguma forma fácil de resolver esta implementação com o JAXB percorrendo o arquivo e dividindo cada um daqueles campos para depois manipular eles em algum lugar?

Comment: O que você quer dizer é que não está conseguindo preencher os valores nos atributos ?

Comment: Isso!! O que estou tentando é ler todo o arquivo `xml` que estou mandando `unmarshalling` e o que quero é separar cada uma das tags e por exemplo gravar cada uma em um `pedido.setDataCadastro(), pedido.setNomeProduto por exemplo`... estou executando os testes pela classe `public static main void (string [] args)` porém o que eu quero fazer é com que na classe ViewPedidos (Formulário JSwing) eu possa carregar o arquivo `xml.` lá dentro dai eu pegue cada valor separadamente de cada tag e insira cada um dentro de uma JTextField, JComboBox... Dai as entradas seriam recebidas em formato `xml`

Comment: Ou seja, quando o usuário carregar o arquivo, os campos de texto recebem os valores do arquivo e o usuário só insere sem preencher